# Insertar php en javascript

Tags: php, javascript

quisiera saber si es posible insertar php en javascript y mostrar el resultado con un innerhtml o algo asi.
Por ejemplo tengo un archivo llamado js.php, en ese archivo tengo una varieble en php , pero quiero mostrarl una parte en la pagina index , es decir que sea dinamico el resultado del inner html.
por ejemplo esta es mi archivo js.php

````
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (<?php echo name; ?>);

</script>  ```
y este es mi archivo index.php
``` <?php include 'js.php'; ?>

<div class="demo"></div> ```
````

Comment: ¿Y la variable name de dónde obtiene su valor?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que javascript se toma muy enserio la sintaxis de el codigo, por lo cual se toma enserio y literal lo de `<?php echo ... ?>`, entonces puedes hacer algo como esto:

```php
<?php
$name = "<h1>Pepito</h1>";
?>

<div id='demo'></div>

<script>
  const el = document.querySelector('#demo');
  el.innerHTML = "<?php echo $name; ?>";
</script>
```

Pagina esperada:

[image: Pagina esperada]

Answer (score 0):

No es posible.
Hay que tener en cuenta que PHP es un lenguaje de programacion del lado del servidor, mientras que JavaScript es un lenguaje del lado del cliente. Mientras que todo tu codigo de PHP lo maneja tu hosting, todo tu codigo escrito en JavaScript sera manejado por el navegador de las personas que ingresen a tu pagina web. Los navegadores no entienden php, al intentar insertar codigo de PHP a una pagina web, lo unico que estas haciendo es dejar el codigo como una cadena de texto dentro del codigo de javascript el cual nunca se va a ejecutar.

Lo que podrias hacer en cambio seria tener el archivo index.php en el cual tengas lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $name = "Steve";
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="demo">
             <?php echo $name; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Esto de por si daria el dejaria el nombre "Steve" dentro de nuestro div sin el uso de JavaScript. Importante mencionar que el archivo debe ser un archivo *php*, no uno *html*.

Es decir: **index.php** estaria correcto y funcionaria pero **index.html** no.